# How to keep values of a union member between function calls in C?

Tags: c

Can someone please tell me how can I keep a value assigned to a union member using a write function, knowing that the union is a member of global queue struct?

Basically what I did is to define one data queue buffer struct with queue name, length and mutexes (for synch between read and write functions). The buffer data are houskeeping structs of different systems; A union was used to encapsulate all of the different structs. Different instances of the queue struct were created for each system (eps_q, com_q..etc).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef union qbuf{
        eps_hk eps_buf[EPS_HK_SIZE];
        odb_hk odb_buf[ODB_HK_SIZE];    
        com_hk com_buf[COM_HK_SIZE];
        cam_hk cam_buf[CAM_HK_SIZE];
        adcs_hk adcs_buf[ADCS_HK_SIZE];
}qbuf_t;

typedef struct {
        qbuf_t  qbuf; 
        int qwindex;
        int qlength;
        int qfull;
        char *qname;
        pthread_mutex_t *qmut; 
        pthread_cond_t *qFull;
}queue;


queue *odb_q;
queue *eps_q;
queue *com_q;
queue *cam_q;
queue *adcs_q;


/*************************************************/
/**** read and write functions in eps.c *****/

int eps_queueAdd (queue *q, eps_hk hk)
{
        q->qbuf.eps_buf[q->qwindex] = hk;
        printf(".... After queue add.....  vbatt %u\n", q->qbuf.eps_buf[q->qwindex].vbatt);
        q->qwindex++;
        if (q->qwindex == q->qlength) {              
            q->qwindex = 0;
            q->qfull=1;
        }
        return (q->qfull);
}


eps_hk eps_queueRead(queue *q)  //read hk from local eps hk table, for hk handlers
{   
    eps_hk hk;
    sleep (10);
    hk = q->qbuf.eps_buf[q->qwindex];
    printf(".... INSIDE queue read .....vbatt %u  \n", q->qbuf.eps_buf[q->qwindex].vbatt);
    return (hk);
}
```

The write function (queueADD) works just fine.The Problem here is that when I try to read the value previously written using (queueADD) (let's say 10), I can't seem to find it (I get a 0).

Thank you for taking the time to read my post =)

=== EDIT ================================================================

My purpose for using the union in the queue struct is to define a generic queue for different data types. Of course, I thought about using a void* pointer but it s too much of a hassle with memory allocation and pointer dereferencing. What do you think?

Comment: Substitute `union` for `struct`? Why is it an `union`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve]: right now, it's not even clear if you're actually allocating any memory for your global pointers to point to. An MCVE for something like this should be something we could copy-paste to e.g. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and see the error ourselves, so it should have all necessary types definitions, a `main`, etc.; and should not contain code not required to reproduce the error.

Comment: `return (hk);` is almost certainly a bug. You shouldn't have any local instances of these structs at all.

Comment: Dear Angew, I would have provided the whole code if it was possible. The previous code is part of a big project tree compiled using make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your write function, you update/increment the index (aka `qwindex`) and in the read function you use the **same index** for reading. So the read-function will return the element **after** the last element that you wrote (i.e. an element that has not been written yet).

I would expect the read function to either

1) take an index of the element you want to read

or

2) use `qwindex - 1` as index (and then decrement the index to get stack-like behavior).

Or maybe you need one index for writes and another index for reads so that the oldest element is returned (FIFO behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You need a enum in queue telling you what member of union is select. Example:

```
typedef enum 
{
   qbuf_select_eps = 0;
   qbuf_select_odb;
   qbuf_select_com;
   qbuf_select_cam;
   qbuf_select_adcs;
}qbuf_select_t;

typedef struct {
        qbuf_t  qbuf; 
        qbuf_select_t qbuf_select;
        int qwindex;
        int qlength;
        int qfull;
        char *qname;
        pthread_mutex_t *qmut; 
        pthread_cond_t *qFull;
}queue;
```

And in function you use switch like this.

```
queue *q;
...

switch (q->qbuf_select)
{
   case qbuf_select_eps:
   //Operations on q->qbuf.eps_buf
   break;
   case qbuf_select_com:
   //Operations on q->qbuf.com_buf
   break;
...
}
```

I used this solution and works fine.

Comment: Although no harm, it is customary to put the selector before the union.